# Use oldstyle numbers for page numbers only, with KOMA-script

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook, oldstylenums

I'm using `newtxtext`/`newpxtext` together with `scrbook` and I'd like to use oldstyle numbers *only* for page numbers, but also for page numbers in the toc.

The former package offers the macro `\useosf`, which is not allowed in combination with

```
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\osf}
```

as it can only be used in the preamble. But `\addtokomafont` also ends up within the document when shipped out.

As a workaround I can use

```
\newcommand\oldstylenumbers{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenumbers}
```

But it does not affect the page numbers in the toc. The only possible option I know of is:

```
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\oldstylenumbers}
```

which is not available for sections and subsections etc.

**How can I change all page numbers in the toc to oldstyle numbers?**

I also read that changing `\thepage` is not recommended as it would break hyperref. That is not desirable.

### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\newcommand\oldstylenumbers{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenumbers}
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\oldstylenumbers}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subection}
123456789 \num{123456789}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change it with the tocpagenumberformat option. There is no need to define your own commands, \oldstylenums works fine.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
\addtokomafont{chapterentrypagenumber}{\oldstylenums}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\oldstylenums]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocpagenumberformat=\oldstylenums]{subsection}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subection}
\oldstylenums{01234}
123456789 \num{123456789}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\chapter{Chapter}
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper
\subsection{Subection}
\blindmathpaper

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! As always my example was too minimal. `\oldstylenums` unfortunately breaks the numbering in case there are parts in the document with roman numbering. However, hidden in the source code of newpxtext and newtxtext I found the commands `\osfstyle` and `\textosf` which work like intended.

Comment: Addendum: You can alternatively use `\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocpagenumberformat=\oldstylenums]{section,subsection}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke that does not work for me

Comment: @thewaywewalk `\RedeclareSectionCommands` has been implemented in the same KOMA-Script version like `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. So it should work for you too. Did you get an error message? Which?

Comment: @Schweinebacke I have overseen the `s` - it does work indeed! thanks!